# How to get a row out of a data frame with multiple arguments

Tags: r

I am trying to get a row 'most_lost' out of the Titanic df.

I created a new variable (most_lost) and want the row of information out of the `Titanic df. most_lost <- unlist(titanic_df[max("Freq"), ])`

I have tried multiple approaches and every time I run it the information comes back NA

`most_lost <- unlist(titanic_df[max("Freq"), ])` with this line of code my data

```
come out
 Class      Sex      Age Survived     Freq 
      NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

I want it to come out

```
Crew Male Adult No 670
```

I have tried

```
most_lost <- titanic_df[max("Freq"), ]
```

and it still returns NA

Comment: Which Titanic data set is this? Well, there are couple of Titanic data sets online and one in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a variable, then it is going to be a column not a row.
Try

```
max(titanic_df[, "Freq"])
```

**Edit**

OK, in case you want to get the row...

```
titanic_df[titanic_df$Freq == max(titanic_df$Freq), ]
```

Or using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
titanic_df %>% 
  filter(Freq == max(Freq))
```

or you can order by freq and take the first row,

```
titanic_df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Freq)) %>% 
  head(1)
```

Comment: Ok that got me the max (670) but I need the entire row of data not just the max